# Does "malloc"ed memory get freed implicitly?

Tags: c, malloc, free

Considering a variable `sTmp` of `(char *)` defined with `malloc`,

If I assign another variable to this `sTmp`, does the memory allocated via this variable get freed automatically or does that memory block remain allocated (& useless) until the process ends?

Let me explain with a code:

```
int main () {
    char *sTmp = (char *) malloc (50);
    char *sNew = strdup ("some text"); // length is less than 50
    sTmp = sNew;
    /*  now sTmp points to sNew and it's length is 10 chars
        I wonder, what happened to the allocated memory of 50 chars in the first line;
        Does it get freed implicitly or remain allocated?
    */
}
```

Comment: You have created a memory leak. The memory is still allocated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since some memory zone has been `malloc`-ed but not `free`-d, you have a [memory leak](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_leak).

However, on most operating systems (notably on Linux and other [POSIX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Posix) systems), the OS is releasing all the resources (including memory) after a [process](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_%28computing%29) has been terminated. So you might decide to not bother too much (at least for data which is `malloc`-ed only once at iniitalization time).

You could use some memory leak detector like [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) and you should compile with all warnings and debug info (e.g. `gcc -Wall -g`) and use a debugger (e.g. `gdb`)

BTW, you might consider using a [garbage collector](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_collection_%28computer_science%29), like [Boehm's conservative garbage collector](http://www.hboehm.info/gc/). You'll then use `GC_MALLOC` instead of `malloc`, `GC_STRDUP` instead of `strdup`, and you won't bother to call `free` (if you did, you'll call `GC_FREE` instead). The GC would usually free inaccessible memory.

Comment: OK... I'm very new to C and instead of messing with "garbage collector" I'd rather stay awake and continue freeing memory explicitly. Thanks.

Comment: I believe you should at least be *aware* of *garbage collection* techniques and terminology (at the very least, read the linked wikipage). Also, learn how to use the debugger and the memory leak detector.

Answer (score 4):

> Does “malloc”ed memory get freed implicitly?

No, there is no garbage collector mechanism in C.

You have to explicitly `free` the memory you allocate with `malloc`

```
sTmp = sNew;
```

This assignment statement causes a memory leak, free the object before the assignment.

Answer (score 1):

memory is allocated and a pointer to it is lost, now you can not free this memory until the end of the program